# Efficiency in Android Activity

Tags: java, android

Which one is more efficient in terms of memory and speed?

- close an activity when you go to another and create a new one when  go back

  or
- not finishing the activity and leave on the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of speed, reusing will be faster rather than creating a new one.

In terms of memory, finishing the activity and creating a new one will use less memory, but you should not worry about it unless you have a large number of activities.

You may not want close the activity if you want to come back to it again.